# Tar file changed as we read it

Tags: archiving, tar

Does tar skip any files that produce the error "file changed as we read it"?  The version of tar I am using is 1.14.

Comment: A version number alone is not sufficient to identify tar.  There are many different implementations.  But I am guessing you are using gnutar since that is becoming the most common.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU tar` 1.23, the `file changed as we read it` warning does not stop `tar` from archiving the file.  When I untarred and inspected the file that raised the error, the file was malformed.

So yes, `GNU tar` will not skip the file, but that file will probably be messed up in some way or another.  If you need to `tar` a directory `foo` whose contents may change, copy `foo` and `tar` the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not....but its contents will be suspect.